# Where can I find Ionic components images for UI design?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

For testing different UI combinations for an Ionic mobile application I have been asked to provide a Ionic components image kit so they can be drag&drop into Photoshop or other editor.

I have been trying to find it without success. Do someone know if this exists and where it is?

Sorry if the question does not belongs here. I am not sure where it does. Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/

Comment: Thanks, Alex. But this is not ready for be dropable into photoshop and downloading all these components can be a pain.